# How to read incidents on the Teams Pro Portal programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

On the Teams Pro portal I can see the incidents logged automatically for Managed Teams Rooms. Even tough MS provides a ServiceNow connector, there's no other out-of the box way to retrieve these incidents.
So I did some tracing on the portal, and it looks like the tickets are coming nicely in json format from an api at `https://mmrprodemeaapi.azurewebsites.net/api/customers/{some kind of customer id}/ticketsanddevices`
I extracted the token from Fiddler and I could get the required data with PowerShell:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://mmrprodemeaapi.azurewebsites.net/api/customers/$tenantid/ticketsanddevices" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="*/*"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "Origin"="https://portal.rooms.microsoft.com"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="cross-site"
  "authorization"="Bearer xxxx"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Not.A/Brand`";v=`"8`", `"Chromium`";v=`"114`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"114`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
}
```

Well, this works fine, until the token expires. However I don't really know how to get this token.

When I try to authenticate with a managed identity with a Logic App workflow, I get further, claiming that that user is not found. True, unfortunately there's no option to add a Managed Identity to a Teams Portal role.

What I have in my hands are:

- my service account username and password
- a full trace of how the incidents are downloaded in the browser
- a bearer token from the trace

My question is:
Is there any way to get the token somehow programamtically?
If not, once I extracted the token, can I refresh it somehow?